# Saving images from a website and accessing it from another website

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created a website let's name it a.com. Now in this website (a.com) the users can upload an image that gets saved to a folder on remote server and the path is getting saved to database.

There is a second website (b.com) which has been hosted on the same server where the image needs to be retrieved.

Can we do this? If yes then please suggest some solution

Language Used = Asp.net 4.0 C#
Backend = SQL2008

Answer (score 0):

Since your using SQL and .Net im going to assume your using IIS aswell,

Creating a Virtual directory is probably your best bet, Easy to setup, easy to manage and Extremely handy to understand (if not vital)

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

This is assuming you want to display the image in b.com, if you simply want to retrieve it you can do so by retrieving the path and using the image in any other way, you may need to set permissions on the image folder.

Answer (score 0):

It cane be done, if both website can access the remote folder. You need to use something like [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to download image from remote server.

Answer (score 0):

first of all both sites should use the same database to share information about images. 
If I understand correctly b.com and the files are on the same server. If so put folder's virtual path to configuration.
After that, check database for new records. If found one, parse the name of the file and find it on the server.

As an example you get an image on a.com and insert it on database as

```
name="image.jpg"
```

b.com checks database for new records and finds image.jpg.
b.com reads configuration and finds

```
path="http://c.com/"
```

combines path and imagename

```
fulllink="http://c.com/image.jpg"
```